# Passing data from a form to a view Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-views, django-forms

I have two functions in views.py, the first one allows you to display information from tables. The second is to get data from the form and redirect to the page with the result. How can I pass the data received from the form to the first function to display information from the tables based on this very data?

In the first function:

```
def SuOp(request): 
    allrooms = Rooms.objects.all()
    allfood = Food.objects.all()
    alltours = Tours.objects.all()  
    
    data = {   
    'allfood': allfood, 
    'allrooms': allrooms,
    'alltours': alltours,
    }

    return render(request, './obj.html', data)
```

in the second function:

```
def Main(request):
    error = ''
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SearchMain(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
              budget = form.cleaned_data.get("budget") 
              arrival_date = form.cleaned_data.get("arrival_date") 
              departure_date = form.cleaned_data.get("departure_date") 
              number_of_people = form.cleaned_data.get("number_of_people")
              count_days = (departure_date-arrival_date).days 
              return redirect('allobject')

        else:
              error = 'The form has been filled out incorrectly'

    form SearchMain()

    data = {
        'formS': form,
        'error': error,
    }

    return render(request, './main.html', data)
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.Main, name='main'),
    path(r'allobject/$', views.SuOp, name='allobject')
]
```

Comment: The usual way is to save the data you receive from your form in `Main` to your `Rooms`, `Food` and `Tours` models, then your `SuOp` will already display them the way you have it now.

Comment: @raphael I use a form to get additional parameters that are not in the tables as separate elements. The received parameters from the form (budget, arrival_date, departure_date, number_of_people) I need to somehow pass to the SuOp function, in which the data output from the tables will be generated based on the received parameters. This is something like filtering, only for a few related models. I do not really understand how I can pass these very entered parameters from the form. Perhaps this is done through url attributes, but I don't understand how :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/sessions/) to pass values from one view to another.  First set the session:

```py
if form.is_valid():
    budget = form.cleaned_data.get("budget")
    request.session['budget'] = budget
    ...
    return redirect('allobject')
```

Then your other view can get the session variable:

```py
def SuOp(request):

    budget = request.session.get('budget')
    ...

    allrooms = Rooms.objects.all()
    allfood = Food.objects.all()
    alltours = Tours.objects.all()  
    
    data = {   
    'allfood': allfood, 
    'allrooms': allrooms,
    'alltours': alltours,
    }

    return render(request, './obj.html', data)
```

The other option is to do all the calculations in the view that receives the budget, arrival_date, departure_date, number_of_people, save the desired results to the `Rooms`, `Food` and `Tours` objects.